# Twitter & Facebook Share Buttons Misaligned

Tags: html, css, facebook, twitter

I added a facebook and twitter share button to the bottom of each of my posts, but the two buttons are misaligned by about 3px and I can't figure out how to make them align with each other.

I tried adding a negative margin to the Facebook widget and also tried adding a positive one to the Twitter widget. The browser ignores it both times (even if I used !important).

You can see the issue here: http://cantstopshipping.com

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<!--FACEBOOK SCRIPT-->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=258039414242053&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <!--/ FACEBOOK SCRIPT-->
    <!--TWITTER SCRIPT-->
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
    <!--/ TWITTER SCRIPT-->

<div class="sharepost">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-via="CantStopShippin" data-hashtags="<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?>" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
      <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-type="box_count"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS I tried to add to fix the issue:

```
.fb-share-button {
    margin-top: -2px !important;
}
```

Also, the CSS of .sharepost (which the chare buttons are inside) is:

```
.sharepost {
width: 325px;
height: 65px;
float: right;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Comment: whats the styles of the object containing this buttons. I found out your problem is made by browsers. because in IE they are aligned correct

Comment: @HKK I don't know because the styles are all contained on Facebook's end. The only two displayed in the inspector are: .fb_iframe_widget {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

Comment: no i, i mean whats around the buttons?
i think this is because, facebook is a div, and twitter is an iframe

Comment: @HKK I have added the .sharepost CSS to the question. That's what's surrounding the share buttons.

Comment: Adding `vertical-align: top;` to `.fb_iframe_widget` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align: top;` to `.fb_iframe_widget` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the buttons into `td`'s, each button in one `<td>`.

example... http://jsfiddle.net/QC6J6/8/

Answer (score 1):

Okay, In reset.css replace `margin: 0px;` with `margin-top: -5px;` (: or replace it with any px amount you want but it need to be negative.

Comment: or do as @Filly sayed.